# what is the difference between Linux ARM ELF and iOS ARM ELF files?

Tags: ios, linux, arm

The subject says it. But just to make it more clear, I wonder what the difference is in detail. I mean binary header, or some data alignment, or ways to map and remap functions or something else you know of?

Can you just use Android ARM ELF binary on iOS? Why not? I mean syscalls? libc? elf format difference? I know Darwin is not Linux. So maybe syscalls. But I am just guessing, I want to know from someone who knows.

For example I compile with arm-ios gcc, and then link with arm-linux ld, what will happen? Will it work? Or why exactly not if not?

Sorry, my wording is messy, because I lack some deep knowledge. But that is why I look for expertise. Otherwise I would know how to find this info myself.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS binaries don't use ELF file format but [mach-o](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html) file format. Which are totally different formats.

Comment: Your link is now broken.